# Is nikah valid after having no intercourse for 4 months incase of injury?

Tags: nikah, wife, husband

I wanted to ask for a lady who had a vertebrae fracture 4 months ago. She and her husband had not engaged in any sexual activity since then. Does this break thier nikah? Waiting for your response. Thank you.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q &A site about Islam. Nikah doesn't invalidate unless a court declares it void based on the request of any of the partners or it ends due to talk, death or alike.